# Does cryptocurrency require blockchain technology?

Tags: blockchain

A decentralized ledger app could have many different implementations. Why do all crypto coins rely on blockchain. Is it really the only way to implement a secure decentralized ledger?

Answer (score 1):

They don't all require on blockchain, look up IOTA, and some use more advanced distributed systems.  In general, the term has become sort of a catch all for the distributed/crypto space.  I would advise reading the [Bitcoin white paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin%20whitepaper&oq=bitcoin%20white&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i65j0l3.2359j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

as that will kind of describe why blockchain is generally used or why you will need something like it followed by the [IOTA white paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=iota%20white%20paper&oq=iota%20white%20paper&aqs=chrome.0.0l2.1931j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), so you can see how a decentralized currency can function without using a by the books blockchain but something based around blockchain.  I would say the bigger thing is the consensus algorithm and how nodes can come to a consensus, in other words, they usually use the concepts behind blockchain.